# I need help with a chinese address

Tags: translation

I am returning an item to a Chinese seller on aliexpress, and this is the return address I was given:

zhao fang 18688795412

China guang dong sheng dong guan shi feng gang zhen long fu hua yuan 1 dong xiang ge li shang wu zhong xin 201
CN 523681 dong guan shi guang dong sheng

Does this look correct? Can someone help me with how to fill out the address from the US, like using FedEx?

Comment: Maybe you should keep the cell phone number to yourself concerning privacy.

Answer (score 3):

> zhao fang 18688795412

This is who it's addressed to; their family name is Zhao (very likely 赵) and their given name Fang (maybe 方).

> China guang dong sheng dong guan shi feng gang zhen long fu hua yuan 1 dong xiang ge li shang wu zhong xin 201 CN 523681 dong guan shi guang dong sheng

Breaking this down:

- China 中国
- Guangdong Province 广东省 = guang dong sheng
- Dongguan City 东莞市 = dong guan shi
- Fenggang Town 凤岗镇 = feng gang zhen
- Longfu Gardens 龙福花园 = long fu hua yuan
- Building 1 1栋 = 1 dong
- Xianggeli Business Center 香格里商务中心 = xiang ge li shang wu zhong xin
- Second floor, office number 1 = 201
- Postcode = 523681

I don't know why "dong guan shi guang dong sheng" is repeated at the end.

Thus in Chinese it's:

> 中国广东省东莞市凤岗镇龙福花园1栋香格里商务中心523681

The office is [here](https://j.map.baidu.com/64/85z):

> [image: photo from street]

You can see the characters characters 龍福花園 (traditional) = 龙福花园 (simplified) and 香格里商务中心 in a closer up photo:

> [image: photo showing characters 龙福花园 and 香格里商务中心]

If there's any complications, whoever is delivering it will just call the phone number.

Comment: Nice answer, one thing: "1 dong" together may mean 1 栋 instead of dong as East?

Comment: Isn't this a translation service? The post offices in China other than in the rural areas are capable of recognizing the address in English.

Comment: Thank you so much for breaking it down for me! I truly appreciate your help!!

Comment: @Archeosudoerus is right - it is 1 栋 (Building 1), not 1 东 (which does not make sense).

Comment: Okay I changed it to 栋; it makes more sense.  (I originally thought it was 东 based on its location on the map.)